# Find the missing element in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am looking at LeetCode problem [268. Missing Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/missing-number/description/):

> Given an array `nums` containing `n` distinct numbers in the range `[0, n]`, return *the only number in the range that is missing from the array*.
>
> #### Example 1
>
> - **Input:** `num = [3,0,1]`
> - **Output:** `2`
> - **Explanation:** `n = 3` since there are 3 numbers, so all numbers are in the range `[0,3]`. 2 is the missing number in the range since it does not appear in `nums`.
>
> #### Example 2
>
> - **Input:** `num = [0,1]`
> - **Output:** `2`
> - **Explanation:** `n = 2` since there are 2 numbers, so all numbers are in the range `[0,2]`. 2 is the missing number in the range since it does not appear in `nums`.
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - `n == num.length`
> - `1 <= n <= 104`
> - All the numbers of `nums` are unique.

Here's my code :

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int Missing_Number(vector<int>& num) {
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i=0 ; i <= nums.size() ; i++){
            bool flag = true;
            for(int j=0 ;j<=nums.size() -1 ; j++){
                if(i == nums[j]){
                    flag = false;
                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(flag == true){
                ans = i;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

I passed all the test cases but eventually end up getting a "time limit exceeded" error. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a *"time limit exceeded"* error because the algorithm you have implemented is not efficient enough. It has a time complexity of O(²), while this can be solved with a time complexity of O().

A hint is: [Triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

Here is a spoiler:

> `class Solution {
>  public:
>      int missingNumber(vector& nums) {
>          int n = nums.size();
>          int sum = std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0);
>          return n * (n + 1) / 2 - sum;
>      }
>  };`

Comment: I liked the spoiler effect ! I didn't know that

Comment: @trincot yeah did already.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, which also uses the notion of comparing a quantity for the full [0:n] range with that for the vector missing a single element is to use repeated xor (^).

I couldn't come up with a general formula for the xor'ing of the first n numbers as you would get for the sum of the triangle numbers. However, I did note that if you xor the first 3, 7, 11, 15, etc. numbers then you keep getting back to 0. (Write it out on paper and then deduce why it has to be thus). So you can reduce your comparator to a maximum of 3 xor operations.

With multiplying and integer-dividing by 4 also reduced to bit operations here is a solution that comes primarily from bitwise operations.

```
int missingNumber( const vector<int> &V )
{
   int n = V.size();
   int a{};
   for ( int i = ( ( n + 1 ) >> 2 ) << 2; i <= n; i++ ) a ^= i;
   for ( int i : V ) a ^= i;
   return a;
}
```